# Tab bar Controller and Facebook Connect Issues Xcode 4.3 IOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to connect to the facebook and take the users name and picture, so far i can connect and fetch user name . i have a working code can be downloaded from here [(single view application)](http://gtiapps.com/misc/FBTestApp.zip)

But if i put a tab bar controller to the code, it can not receive a response from facebook.

I add a tabbar controller programatically like below code 
in app.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Regular Code 
    /*self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    */
   //Tab bar controller code
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];    
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.rootController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

// This method will be used for iOS versions greater than 4.2.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

If i put a breaking point at line handleOpenurl In NSUrl there is this= `fbAPPID://authorize/#access_token=BABABSbbsabsbabb`
 I guess access_token means i have succesfully loged in . So tab bar doesnt block me to login put blokcs my facebook methods in Viewcontroller.m

Without tab bar all methods in Viewcontroller.m works great when i add tab bar and breakpoints none of the facebook methods below works. I dont get any errors though.

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
-(void)fbDidLogin
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "Facebook.h"


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btnLogin;
@synthesize btnPublish;
@synthesize lblUser;
@synthesize actView;
@synthesize facebook;
@synthesize permissions;
@synthesize isConnected;
@synthesize imageView;

// The alert view that will be shown while the game will upload to facebook.
UIAlertView *msgAlert;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


-(void)checkForPreviouslySavedAccessTokenInfo{
    // Initially set the isConnected value to NO.
    isConnected = NO;

    // Check if there is a previous access token key in the user defaults file.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] &&
        [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];

        // Check if the facebook session is valid.
        // If it’s not valid clear any authorization and mark the status as not connected.
        if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
            [facebook authorize:nil];
            isConnected = NO;
        }
        else {
            isConnected = YES;
        }
    }
}


-(void)setLoginButtonImage{
    UIImage *imgNormal;
    UIImage *imgHighlighted;
    UIImageView *tempImage;

    // Check if the user is connected or not.
    if (!isConnected) {
        // In case the user is not connected (logged in) show the appropriate
        // images for both normal and highlighted states.
        imgNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginNormal.png"];
        imgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginPressed.png"];
    }
    else {
        imgNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LogoutNormal.png"];
        imgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LogoutPressed.png"];
    }

    // Get the screen width to use it to center the login/logout button.
    // We’ll use a temporary image view to get the appopriate width and height.
    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;    
    tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgNormal];
    [btnLogin setFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth / 2 - tempImage.frame.size.width / 2, btnLogin.frame.origin.y, tempImage.frame.size.width, tempImage.frame.size.height)];

    // Set the button’s images.
    [btnLogin setBackgroundImage:imgNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLogin setBackgroundImage:imgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    // Release the temporary image view.
    [tempImage  release];
}


-(void)showActivityView{
    // Show an alert with a message without the buttons.
    msgAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My test app" message:@"Please wait..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [msgAlert show];

    // Show the activity view indicator.
    actView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
    [actView setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0, 350.0)];
    [actView setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:actView];
    [actView startAnimating];
}


-(void)stopShowingActivity{
    [actView stopAnimating];
    [msgAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}


-(void)saveAccessTokenKeyInfo{
    // Save the access token key info into the user defaults.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Set the permissions.
    // Without specifying permissions the access to Facebook is imposibble.
    permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"publish_stream", nil] retain];

    // Set the Facebook object we declared. We’ll use the declared object from the application
    // delegate.
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"331327710279153" andDelegate:self];

    // Check if there is a stored access token.
    [self checkForPreviouslySavedAccessTokenInfo];


    // Depending on the access token existence set the appropriate image to the login button.
    [self setLoginButtonImage];

    // Specify the lblUser label's message depending on the isConnected value.
    // If the access token not found and the user is not connected then prompt him/her to login.
    if (!isConnected) {
        [lblUser setText:@"Tap on the Login to connect to Facebook"];
    }
    else {
        // Get the user's name from the Facebook account.
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];


    }

    // Initially hide the publish button.
    [btnPublish setHidden:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setBtnLogin:nil];
    [self setLblUser:nil];
    [self setBtnPublish:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // Keep this just for testing purposes.
    NSLog(@"received response");
}


-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
    // With this method we’ll get any Facebook response in the form of an array.
    // In this example the method will be used twice. Once to get the user’s name to
    // when showing the welcome message and next to get the ID of the published post.
    // Inside the result array there the data is stored as a NSDictionary.    
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // The first object in the result is the data dictionary.
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }



    // Check it the “first_name” is contained into the returned data.
    if ([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]) {
        // If the current result contains the "first_name" key then it's the user's data that have been returned.
        // Change the lblUser label's text.
        [lblUser setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!", [result objectForKey:@"first_name"]]];
        // Show the publish button.
        [btnPublish setHidden:NO];
    }
    else if ([result objectForKey:@"id"]) {
        // Stop showing the activity view.
        [self stopShowingActivity];

        // If the result contains the "id" key then the data have been posted and the id of the published post have been returned.
        UIAlertView *al = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My test app" message:@"Your message has been posted on your wall!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [al show];
        [al release];
    }
}


-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    // Stop the activity just in case there is a failure and the activity view is animating.
    if ([actView isAnimating]) {
        [self stopShowingActivity];
    }
}


-(void)fbDidLogin{
    // Save the access token key info.
    [self saveAccessTokenKeyInfo];

    // Get the user's info.
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}


-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled{
    // Keep this for testing purposes.
    //NSLog(@"Did not login");

    UIAlertView *al = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My test app" message:@"Login cancelled." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [al show];
}


-(void)fbDidLogout{
    // Keep this for testing purposes.
    //NSLog(@"Logged out");

    // Hide the publish button.
    [btnPublish setHidden:YES];
}


- (IBAction)LoginOrLogout {
    // If the user is not connected (logged in) then connect.
    // Otherwise logout.
    if (!isConnected) {
        [facebook authorize:permissions];

        // Change the lblUser label's message.
        [lblUser setText:@"Please wait..."];
    }
    else {
        [facebook logout:self];
        [lblUser setText:@"Tap on the Login to connect to Facebook"];
    }

    isConnected = !isConnected;
    [self setLoginButtonImage];
}

- (IBAction)Publish {
    // Show the activity indicator.
    [self showActivityView];

    // Create the parameters dictionary that will keep the data that will be posted.
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My test app", @"name",
                                   @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                                   @"FBTestApp app for iPhone!", @"caption",
                                   @"This is a description of my app", @"description",
                                   @"Hello!\n\nThis is a test message\nfrom my test iPhone app!", @"message",              
                                   nil];

    // Publish.
    // This is the most important method that you call. It does the actual job, the message posting.
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [btnLogin release];
    [lblUser release];
    [btnPublish release];
    [actView release];
    [facebook release];
    [permissions release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I am confused how can i make this tab bar controlling working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed the design

Now Login view is displayed first then it continues to real app which has tab bar controller.

Issue was _viewcontroller facebook , when _viewcontroller has been called it was not returning any thing

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

So I changed my code(especially _viewcontroller line) to below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    UIViewController * viewController1 = [[[VoteMe alloc] initWithNibName:@"VoteMe" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[PostController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PostController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[FriendsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[Responses alloc] initWithNibName:@"Responses" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[[User alloc] initWithNibName:@"User" bundle:nil] autorelease];


    self.rootController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2,viewController3,viewController4,viewController5, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    loginView=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:loginView.view];

    return YES;

}

// This method will be used for iOS versions greater than 4.2.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[loginView facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

It works fine